# Pytorch tensor to numpy conversion imprecision

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I am using pytorch to build a network model that outputs a probabilistic distribution, after obtaining predictions i want to transform them into a numpy array for further processing, although, when doing that, the converted array is not precise, that is, the values differ from the original (see example below). This is specially bad in my case because, considering the imprecision, the rows does not sum exactly 1 anymore, which is causing me issues further into the code, any ideas on why this is happening? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
>> predictions
Out[34]: 
tensor([[0.0155, 0.0260, 0.2671, 0.6820, 0.0093],
        [0.1231, 0.1076, 0.1660, 0.5376, 0.0658],
        [0.0734, 0.0501, 0.1683, 0.6602, 0.0480],
        ...,
        [0.0260, 0.0287, 0.0465, 0.8830, 0.0159],
        [0.0251, 0.0327, 0.3148, 0.5643, 0.0632],
        [0.0105, 0.0116, 0.2723, 0.6702, 0.0354]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<CopySlices>)

>> predictions.cpu().detach().numpy()
Out[33]: 
array([[0.01549727, 0.02597333, 0.26714763, 0.68203545, 0.00934631],
       [0.12310678, 0.10758312, 0.16596784, 0.53758585, 0.06575638],
       [0.07338995, 0.05007047, 0.16834012, 0.6601813 , 0.04801816],
       ...,
       [0.02603309, 0.02868567, 0.046453  , 0.8829591 , 0.01586908],
       [0.02508399, 0.03266559, 0.31480333, 0.564255  , 0.06319207],
       [0.01048695, 0.01161059, 0.2722554 , 0.6702131 , 0.03543395]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Just looks like the two libraries are using a different number of digits to round to.  I'm sure the values are the same.  As for why they don't sum to exactly 1: floating point math.

Comment: Isn't this a difference in printing only? seems like both array and tensor rows add up to 1 (or equally don't)

Comment: Take a look at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_printoptions.html; note that the default precision for printed output is 4, while for numpy it is 8.